# Radio button disappears after showing a MessageBox

Tags: c#, user-controls, radio-button, messagebox

I have a C# user control.
In this control, I have a GroupBox that includes radio buttons and textboxes.

When the user switches between the radio buttons, a message box is raised to ask the user if he is sure in his selection.

The top of the messagebox is covering the last radio button and the last textbox.
In a case the user selects NOT to apply the radio button changes, the messagebox is getting closed, but the last radio button (that was covered by the messagebox) disappered. (The last textbox that was also covered by the messagebox is not getting disappered).

This is kind of refresh problem, because when I move the mouse button on the place of the last radio button, it appears again and everything is fine. (it appears again also if I minimize and maximize my application, etc).

I tried to run the methods `Show()` and `Refresh()` on the last radio button after closing of the messagebox, but it doesn't work.

What else can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a Code example?

Comment: refreshing the radio button redraws the radio button and it's children. Maybe the problem is the groupbox needs refreshing?

Comment: Nothing should need refreshing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Application.DoEvents()` after the `MessageBox` closes to ensure there are no other processes in the processing queue. This should re-show the button but it is difficult to tell if you do not show any code as there could be other issues.